# Why does SSIS open the excel file I am importing?

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, import-from-excel

I import multiple excel files into my database. But for some reason the biggest one (14000 rows) actually opens the excel application to read in the data like I opened it from windows explorer, and doesn't close it.

None of the other excel files do this. I tried recreating the task and connection and does the same thing. Is there a setting I can force to not open? Seems bizarre and I can't find anything related online.

Has anyone ran into this problem?

Using VS2019, .xlsx import file

Comment: I've never seen this before. Most servers don't even have Excel on them.

Comment: Are there any scripts in this Excel file? I'm not sure how SSIS deals with macros, but look for `Sub Workbook_Open()` in VBA when you open this excel file.

Comment: It happens the same to me I disabled the data flow task validation and the data is going into a temp table in SQL Server, is there anything similar with your project?

Answer (score 0):

Classic Excel issue. Ctrl + Shift + Esc AKA Task Manager. Kill any lingering, rogue Excel threads. There's a final step, but if you think you're good at this point and reattempt to run your SSIS package, you'll get an error that 'someone' has an exclusive lock on the excel source file. That someone is apparently VS. So close out of VS and reopen.